# PayPal-Cordova-Plugin Cannot find symbol Version

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I've downloaded and installed the PayPal-Cordova-Plugin on my ionic/cordova project.

When I try to build the project I get this error:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/guy/Projects/TreatsForLife/mobile/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [javac] /home/guy/Projects/TreatsForLife/mobile/platforms/android/src/com/paypal/cordova/sdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.callbackContext.success(Version.PRODUCT_VERSION);
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable Version
    [javac]   location: class PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin
    [javac] 1 error
```

I've did some search and found this line in the plugin.xml file

`<engines><engine name="cordova" version="&gt;=3.0.0" /></engines>`

I changed it to what I think is supposed to be there:

`<engines><engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" /></engines>`

But still, the same error occurs.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regression should now be fixed in the latest version of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gets this error, the solution is here:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin/issues/18

Comment: were you able to actually get the paypal plugin to work with ionic? Could you provide some pointers, as I am running into problems getting the plugin to work with Ionic. Thanks in advance.